# Merge two data set lead to duplicate rows or no duplicate rows but with NA data in R by Tidyverse

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two data set with same columns of "Breed" which represent dog breeds, data1 have dog traits and score for it, data2 have same breed as data1 with there rank of popularity in America from 2013 -2020. I have trouble when trying to merge two data set into one. It either shows NA on the 2013-2020 rank information or it shows duplicate rows of same breed, one rows are data from data set 1 and another row is data from data set 2. The closest i can get is by using merge(x,y, by = 'row.names', all = TRUE) and i get all data in correctly but with two duplicated column of Breed.x and Breed.y. I am looking for a way to solve it with one Breed column only and all data in correctly.

here is the data i am using, breed_traits is the data set 1 i am saying, breed_rank_all is the data set 2 i want to merge in to breed_traits

```
breed_traits <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-02-01/breed_traits.csv')
trait_description <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-02-01/trait_description.csv')
breed_rank_all <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-02-01/breed_rank.csv')
```

this is the function i used with the most correctly one but with

```
Breed.y
breed_total <- merge(breed_traits, breed_rank_all, by = c('row.names') , all =TRUE)
breed_total
```

i tried left join as well but it shows NA on the 2013-2020 rank

```
library(dplyr)
breed_traits |> left_join(breed_rank_all, by = c('Breed'))
```

this is the one i tried as well and return duplicated rows of same breed.

```
merge(breed_traits, breed_rank_all, by = c('row.names', 'Breed'), all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Unless the error is with importing the data, it is much better to include your data via e.g. the output of `dput(head(data))`, rather than requiring data to be downloaded from external links.

Comment: sorry for any inconvenience, this is my first time using this site so I am not really sure how to post a question in a proper format.